# Get previous week by date.js expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetime, jquery-plugins

I'm using [daterangepicker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker/) that uses date.js for date ranges presets.
I'm trying to get 'previous week' dates by using date.js expressions.
`Date.parse("sun")`returns me last "Sunday".
How can I get "Sunday" before last one.
In code I can do it with `Date.parse("sun").add({days: -7})`, but how can I do it with expression?

Comment: In plain JS you'd do: `d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() - 7)`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean how can I do it with date.js expression. Something like Date.parse("prev sun")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is forward to the plug-in the following function:

```
function () { return Date.parse("last sun").addDays(-7); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```
Date.parse('t - 7d')
```

Which says **"today minus 7 days"**.

Check out [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for more information on what you can and can't parse using the script.

Comment: I need last and previous Sunday, "t-7d" is last 7 days.

Comment: Hmm, why exactly do you require this syntax? Retrieving it from a datasource I'm guessing?

Comment: I'm using [daterangepicker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker/)  plugin that required this syntax for dates presets...